# Using alternative for multiple inheritance to cast between classes in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

I have three classes `Trench`, `Water` and `Pool`. Now `Pool` shall be a fusion of `Water` and `Trench` so that I can cast between these Types, for instance I want to cast an object of `Pool` into an object of `Trench`, because all properties of `Water` are being removed. First I thought about making `Pool` easily inherit from both `Trench` and `Water`. I just found out, that this is not possible in Java.

Now whats an alternative so that I can cast between the classes as I have mentioned? I've read about using interfaces in Java as alternative for multiple inheritance, but does this casting, how i want it, work when using interfaces? I haven't completely got it.

Answer (score 0):

When Class X implements interfaces A and B, and you have a reference to X, you can also call A's and B's methods. If you have reference to A and it is an instance of X, you could cast it to X, but it is usally not a good a idea to make casts, it is better to avoid such a design.